# Regex to find string pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a requirement to find a text pattern [anystring].[anystring] with in a larger text.

I wrote a regex code to achieve this

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]\.\[(.*?)\]";
string CustomText = "some text here [anystring].[anystring] some text here etc"
var matchesfound = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(CustomText, pattern);
```

This code works fine and detects the "[string].[string]" pattern but it fails for this

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]\.\[(.*?)\]";
string CustomText = "[somestring]=[anystring].[anystring]"
var matchesfound = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(CustomText, pattern)
```

In the above scenario, it identifies the whole string "[somestring]=[anystring].[anystring]" but I want only "[anystring].[anystring]" to be identified as match. Any help with this please? Thank you.

Comment: Use `\[([^][]*)\]\.\[([^][]*)\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
\[([^][]*)]\.\[([^][]*)]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%29%5C%5D%5C.%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%29%5C%5D&i=some%20text%20here%20%5Banystring%5D.%5Banystring%5D%20some%20text%20here%20etc%0D%0A%5Bsomestring%5D%3D%5Banystring%5D.%5Banystring%5D). *Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\.\[` - `].[` substring
- `([^][]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZTW0mD):

```cs
var pattern = @"\[([^][]*)]\.\[([^][]*)]";
var CustomText = "[somestring]=[anystring].[anystring]";
var matchesfound = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(CustomText, pattern);
foreach (Match m in matchesfound) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group 1: {m.Groups[1].Value}\nGroup 2: {m.Groups[2].Value}");
}
```

Output:

```cs
Group 1: anystring
Group 2: anystring
```